# Vue3: Can I return a component in a composition javascript function?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I've got the following composable function:

```
import { DeleteFunction, DjangoModel, JsonModel, Reffed } from "@/types/shared";
import { ref, Ref, unref } from "vue";

export default function useDeleteItem<
  Fn extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<void>, // eslint-disable-line
>(
  deleteItemFunc: Fn,
  items: Ref<DjangoModel[]>,
  ...params: Reffed<Parameters<Fn>>
) {
  const deleteModalOpen = ref(false);

  const deleteRequest: DeleteFunction = (data: JsonModel) => {
    return deleteItemFunc(data, ...params.map(unref)).then(() => {
      deleteModalOpen.value = false;
      items.value = items.value.filter((item) => item.id !== data.id);
    });
  };

  return {
    deleteRequest,
    deleteModalOpen,
  };
}
```

Would it be possible to also return the Modal Component from my file `ModalFree.vue`? I can't figure out if that is possible.

Comment: What is your ModalFree.vue and how would you like to use the Modal component if you can expose it through the return statement?

Comment: I imagined to just prefill its props and return it. So that I can use it in my other file like any other component. I would just add it to the end of the page.

Comment: Component is nothing but a plain JS object (think of it as a spec). So creating component on the fly is fine and not difficult. It does not even need to be tied with .vue files. What is tricky is how you would like to use such a component (defined dynamically). Usually for dynamically constructed component you pretty much have to use render function somewhere (making it very similar to react actually).

Comment: I want to use it from the ModalFree.vue file. And then use it in my page components like this: <ModalFree />